# MEF - ImportMany with generic interfaces & Lazy<T, TMetadata>

Tags: c#, generics, mef

I'm working on an application using MEF (specifically, [MEF 2 Preview 5](http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/79090)), and I've run into a problem trying to import based on a generic interfaces.

I have an interface:

```
public interface IMessageHandler<in T>
{
    void HandleMessage(T message);
}
```

where T is a type of message to be handled. I'm importing these things into a catalog using the `RegistrationBuilder`:

```
RegistrationBuilder context = new RegistrationBuilder();

context.ForTypesDerivedFrom(typeof(IMessageHandler<>))
    .Export(builder => builder.AsContractType(typeof(IMessageHandler<>)));
```

and then, in the consuming class I'm using `[ImportMany]` to import a list of these into an `IEnumerable<Lazy>>`:

```
[ImportMany(typeof(IMessageHandler<>))]
IEnumerable<Lazy<IMessageHandler<object>, HandledMessageTypeAttribute>> _messageHandlers;
```

Now, here lies the first problem - you're forced to assign a type to the generic interface at this point. I'm using `Lazy<T, TMetadata>` as the `IMessageHandler<T>` implementations have relevant metadata I want to consume (`HandledMessageTypeAttribute`).

Now, when I want to access any element in the `IEnumerable<Lazy<>>` collection I get the following exception:

```
Cannot cast the underlying exported value of type 
'MessageHandlerImplementation (ContractName="IMessageHandler(System.Object)")' 
to type 'IMessageHandler`1[System.Object]'.
```

I understand (roughly) why I'm getting the exception, the problem is I have no idea how to get around it. So, basically what I want to do is:

1. Have a bunch of classes which implement an `IMessageHandler<T>` interface.
2. Have them discovered at runtime with MEF.
3. Import them into a collection which allows me to consume any metadata they have.
4. Be able to instantiate them.

I understand I could simply make `IMessageHandler` non-generic and have `IMessageHandler.HandleMessage()` accept a parameter of type `object` but I was looking for a slightly more elegant solution

Any pointers or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a much better way to do what you're trying to achieve without using a non-generic interface. The root of the problem is the interface's definition:

```
public interface IMessageHandler<in T>
```

which means that if we have two classes, `A` and `B`, where `B` derives from `A`, then this is allowed

```
IMessageHandler<B> handler = new AHandler();
```

but this is not:

```
IMessageHandler<A> handler = new BHandler();
```

You're essentially trying to perform the latter, which is what causes the exception to be thrown. I assume that what you'd like to do is to be able to get a handler, given a type. If that's the case then you should probably use a non-generic interface and have the message type available in the export metadata. Then you'll have something like this:

```
public IMessageHandler GetHandler<T>()
{
    Type handlerType = typeof(T);
    return _messageHandlers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Metadata.MessageType == handlerType);
}
```

You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9992159/389966) relevant as well. Hope this helps.